# once a file has been uploaded to the upload directory in expresssionengine can it be moved on my server?

Tags: assets

Can I move files that have been uploaded to the upload directory be moved on my server, or will they be lost in the upload directory and therefore not show on the site?

Answer (score 1):

Moving the files will prevent them being served on the site as your templates will be looking in the upload directory for them.

You can move/copy them and then change the upload directory to the new location if this is what you want to achieve. This is done in `Content > Files > File Upload Preferences` and then clicking 'Edit' next to the folder you want to move.

You may need to synchronise the files after doing this.

Hope this helps :)